# How to fix "Error 400: Invalid value at 'job.pubsub_target.data' (TYPE_BYTES)" for terraform resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-scheduler

I have the following `gcloud` function for google cloud scheduler which works perfectly fine. However I cannot figure out how to put that in terraform just because of one parameter under the `pubsub_target { data = ""` field.

This is the error I keep getting. 
`google_cloud_scheduler_job.c4c_intel_sources_scheduler: Error creating Job: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value at 'job.pubsub_target.data' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for "{"scheduler".......`

No idea how to resolve this error

`Terraform definition`

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "c4c_sources_scheduler" {
  name    = "${var.cluster}-sources-scheduler"
  description = "Creating Sources Scheduler Job"
  count = "${var.c4c_intel_sources_enabled ? 1 : 0}"
  provider = "google-beta"
  project = "${var.project}"
  schedule = "${var.c4c_intel_sources_schedule}"
  region="us-east1"
  pubsub_target {
    topic_name = "${google_pubsub_topic.c4c_sources_topic.id}"
    data = "{\"scheduler\": [ {\"__type\":  \"processors.google_cloud.scheduler\",\"state_bucket\": \"$STATE_BUCKET\",\"state_path\": \"scheduler_state.json\",\"config_bucket\": \"$CONFIG_BUCKET\",\"topic\": \"$TOPIC\"}]}"
```

Equivalent `gcloud definition`

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create pubsub shoaib-test-c4c-intel-sources-scheduler \
--schedule="0 * * * *" \
--topic="projects/eng-node-163913/topics/test-intel-sources"\
--message-body="{\"scheduler\":\ [ {\"__type\": \"processors.google_cloud.scheduler\",\\"state_bucket\": \"$STATE_BUCKET\",\"state_path\": \\"scheduler_state.json\",\\"config_bucket\": \"$CONFIG_BUCKET\",\\"topic\": \"$TOPIC\"}]}" \
--description="C4C Intel Sources Scheduler" \
--project=engineering-node
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to Base64Encode the pubsub_target.data element, as shown in their docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloud_scheduler_job.html

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {
  name     = "test-job"
  description = "test job"
  schedule = "*/2 * * * *"

  pubsub_target {
    topic_name = "${google_pubsub_topic.topic.id}"
    data = "${base64encode("test")}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)